React Router 6.4
I'm trying to create a dashboard page. I want the user to see the dashboard only when they are logged in, else direct to login page.
1- If user manually try to enter any other url that is not valid, it should redirect to login page if not logged in.
2- If user manually try to enter any other url that is not valid, it should redirect to dashboard page if they are logged in.
I managed to do this with the old react router but I am struggling to implement this on the new feature of react router.
Any advise would be helpful.
App.js
const App = () => {
  const user = localStorage.getItem('user');

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<ProtectedRoutes user={user} />}>
        <Route index element={<Navigate to='/dashboard' />} />
        <Route path='/dashboard/*' element={<Dashboard />} />
        <Route path='*' element={<Navigate to='/dashboard' />} />
      </Route>

      <Route
        path='/auth/*'
        element={user ? <Navigate to='/dashboard' /> : <Authenticate />}
      />
    </Routes>
  );
};

ProtectedRoute.js
const ProtectedRoutes = ({ user }) => {
  return user ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to='/auth/login' />;
};

export default ProtectedRoutes;

Authenticate.js
const Authenticate = () => {
  const set = () => {
    localStorage.setItem('user', 'deep');
  };
  return (
    <div className='auth'>
      <div className='auth__screen'>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='register' element={<RegisterPage />} />
          <Route path='verify-email/:verifyToken' element={<VerifyPage />} />
          <Route path='login' element={<LoginPage />} />
          <Route path='forgot' element={<ForgotPage />} />
          <Route path='reset-password/:passwordToken' element={<ResetPage />} />
          <Route path='*' element={<Navigate to='/auth/login' />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
      <button className='form__button' onClick={set}>
        SET
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};


If dashboard component renders sidebar, header and main components, above works but i like to use newer features like loader, error etc, just need need help to change so it works.
Any help would be apreaciated.

Your ProtectedRoutes component logic is really basic and appears fine. What exactly is the issue or problem you face? The only issue I see is that you are trying to use localStorage as your source of truth, and you are only reading it when App renders. Maybe move const user = localStorage.getItem('user'); into the ProtectedRoutes component or implement some React state that will trigger component rerenders when it is updated.

I kept it basic for now so I can test it and all code above works. Im trying to migrate to route provider from browser router.
https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v6-data
Just struggling as i want to keep the same redirecting in places.

Do you have actual need to use a data router? Seems you have need to implement a react auth state so it can be provided to test of the app. Have you tried anything yet that you could share in your post?
